# How to source first name and last name from shipto field in Netsuite Advanced PDF?

Tags: pdf, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

How to pick the firstname and lastname from the Ship to field in Advanced pdf?
i need to get this in my advanced pdf printout.

I tried using `${record.custrecord50}<!-- custrecord50 is the field id -->`
as well as, `${record.shipaddress.custrecord50}`
but both didnt work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try
`record.address.custrecord50`

Here is available address record fied
[image]